# Are there new beamer templates other than the defaults?

Tags: beamer, templates

I have to make a presentation in LaTeX, the `beamer` themes have now become mundane.

So, I have two questions:

1. I tried to use the `Stockholm` template. I downloaded the zip from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi36JfI_fvKAhVOHY4KHdioD4UQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.overleaf.com%2Flatex%2Ftemplates%2Fstockholm-beamer-theme%2Fxjysnqdxfjbc&usg=AFQjCNGq1_tKsnn5K6_EwlX0QsBUbCFlnw&bvm=bv.114195076,d.c2E). I was unable to even compile it in LaTeXila and TeXmaker (Ubuntu). There are only 2 errors but I can't figure them out (I am not posting the errors).

   [Click here for the template at overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/4352270fzgqbw) (Just click download as zip button on the left hand side panel).

With Latexilla the errors are:

```
You have requested package `beamercolorthemesthlm',but the package provides `beamercolorthemev42'.

You have requested package `beamercolorthemesthlm',but the package provides `beamercolorthemev42'.   

File `newpxtext.sty' not found.
```

2. Are there any newer presentation templates for `beamer` ?

Thanks

Comment: Anything that would be helpful in this case is heartily welcome, I dont want to make another presentation in ...

Comment: Hi. It would help a lot, if you posted the errors and a MWE of your template. A first issue for me is that `\usetheme{sthlm}` of the linked template is not found: Where is it pprovided or where can it be obtained?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT will the edit help ?

Comment: I just use `beamer` with no 'theme' at all: really these things are better suited to sales pitches than academic presentations

Comment: @JosephWright yes I agree, but will everybody using fancy ppts -- some use prezi and 3d ppts for academic presentations as well -- I too want to improve my presentations -- step by step

Comment: The edit does not help. You linked a template that is basically the first link. What you need are the style-files (.sty). These are not provided with your template and they are not part of any official latex package. I took the liberty to google the style and found this github-repository. Download the file and extract them into your project folder. It should run smoothly. https://github.com/hendryolson/sthlmBeamerTheme

Comment: It says that sthml is based on a font that is not free and also heavily based on mtheme whatever that is.

Comment: @JosephWright There are probably a lot of bad themes out there. And I also don't agree with some of the design decisions in the `sthlm` theme. But why do you think the [metropolis](https://github.com/matze/mtheme) theme (`sthlm` is based on it) suitable for academic presentation?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT No, I get the same errors. Did you get it working smoothly ?

Comment: Yes, it comiled without errors. What errors do you get anyways? Please state them, to help us helping you.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT I have put them, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks a lot for the reference, any more "modern" latex themes Metropolis and Stockholm ?

Comment: Does it work now? Btw: What do you mean with 'more modern' styles?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT I extracted the github repo, THe errors are from trying to run that extracted project only .

Comment: @HATEthePLOT more modern .. just better than the cliched beamer themes

Comment: I am definitely biased, as I am involved with the development of `metropolis`, but I think you should use it instead of the `sthlm` theme. Imho `sthlm` is just an outdated version of metropolis with another font and different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error

```
You have requested package `beamercolorthemesthlm',but the package provides `beamercolorthemev42'..
```

is just a naming error in the theme. Meaning the filename doesn't match the name given in the `\ProvidesPackage{}` command. This should not prevent you from typesetting a presentation with it.

The actual problem seems to be, that you don't have the `newpx` package installed which the theme uses. So please update your packages:

[How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

---

**EDIT:**
If you cannot, because of whatever reason, update your packages and install `newpx` you can also remove the `newPxFont` option when loading beamer. So replace:

```
\documentclass[newPxFont,sthlmFooter]{beamer}
```

with

```
\documentclass[sthlmFooter]{beamer}
```

in the template file. This way the `newpx` package will not be used.

Comment: I get the error: newpxtext.sty not found ...

Comment: Still? Even though you updated all your packages with `tlmgr update --all`?

Comment: I think I spotted the problem: The template provides ty files as well which I oversaw at first. However, the sty-files from the github repo I posted are working fine. The ones from the original template provided by ferrer are different.

Answer (score 2):

The provided template needs specific sty-files that can be obtained at this [Github-Repository](https://github.com/hendryolson/sthlmBeamerTheme). They need to be extracted into the project-folder to seccessfully compile the template.

Comment: any more files you needed to add to the project ? The repo itself is not working .. same errors.

Comment: Just for understanding: You have your project file from the template you linked in your first post. In the folder where you saved the presentation you unzip the github files. Then you compile the presentation template from your first link. It should work fine. sty-files are not to compile.

Comment: Thanks, its not working for me strangely....

Comment: Do you have all files in the same folder? The sty-files need to be in the same folder and not a subfolder. I tried it on three machines (Ubuntu, Windows and Windows, texlive2014 and 2015). ist works without problems.

Comment: yes, they are in the same folder. I don't see any difference between the github repo and the template I posted. 3 .sty files in both. ARe you sure the github link repo isn't the same ?